# Why last rows are printed in the middle of the page if there's a lot of empty space?

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, reportbuilder3.0, dynamics-business-central

I'm developing this report:

[image]

The problem I'm facing when printing a document with multiple lines is that rows are not printing together when there is a lot of space for it:

[image]

[image]

Header properties:

[image]

Footer properties:

[image]

I don't know why it's not printing on top of the 2nd page header and it leaves a huge blank space... there is also enough space in the 1st page to print all rows

Report property **ConsumeContainerWhitespace** is set as **True**

How can I use all that empty space with the rows instead of printing blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header and footer are fixed spaces. This means that even if you hide the content on one or more pages, the space will still be reserved on layout.

The result is that the space available for the lines is limited on each page and the render engine needs to split them to multiple pages.

You can solve the issue with the header by moving it to at header row in the tablix.

The footer is not possible to do any different if the placement at the bottom of the page is a requirement.